# $firebaseAuthProvider <- $firebaseAuth <- Auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created 1 user account in Firebase and I just need to authenticate that but getting error like 
`$firebaseAuthProvider <- $firebaseAuth <- Auth`

**My app.js:**

```
    var mypractice = angular.module("firebase.appauth", ['practicecontroller','firebase','ngRoute','ngMessages' ]);
```

Service method: I created a separate factory for Authentication:

```
    mypractice.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
        function($firebaseAuth) {
            var ref = $firebaseAuth(new Firebase("https://firabaseurl.com"));

            return $firebaseAuth(ref);
        }
    ]);
```

Controller:

```
practicecontroller.controller("loginctrl", ['$scope', '$http', 'Auth', function ($scope, $http, Auth) {
    $scope.auth = Auth;
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function (authData) {
        $scope.authData = authData;
    });

    $scope.login = function () {
        Auth.$authWithPassword({
            email : $scope.username,
            password : $scope.password
        })
        .then(function (authData) {
            console.log('Logged in as:', authData.uid);

            window.location.href = "#/login/home"

        })
        .catch (function (err) {
            console.log('error:', err);
            //$state.go('login');
        });
    };
```

Comment: What versions of Firebase and AngularFire are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You don't inject `$firebaseAuth` you just use `firebase` directly. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

```
firebase.auth()...
```